# Class not able to recognize maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a maven project. I added the dependencies as jar files and importing them in my class. But the class doesn't recognize it.

I tried a couple of options and serached but couldn't resolve. Please guide.

Attached below is the screenshot of my project str
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the pom

Comment: @ritesh.garg Added

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right click your project and select `maven` then click `update project`. Select the project and select `force update of snapshots/releases` option. Then refresh the project and build it (if you do not see `compilation error` after updating).

Answer (score 0):

Since the jar is not under web-inf folder you are seeing this error.
There are several ways to resolve this issue

1. add below profile

   ```
   <profile>
         <id>qa</id>
         <build>
           <plugins>
             <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                 <execution>
                   <phase>install</phase>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                   </configuration>
                 </execution>
               </executions>
             </plugin>
           </plugins>
         </build>
       </profile>
   ```
2. Dependencies directory created in target folder

   ```
     mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies
   ```

Comment: I was able to resolve this checking Download repository index updates on startup in Window->Pref->Maven. And it  build successfully. However, I am unable to find my generated jar file. Could you please help me out here?

Comment: I found it in target folder when I added <packaging>jar</packaging> in pom.xml. @Tanvi B: Thanks for your reply. Just wanted to confirm the way I fixed dependency issues by setting the checking above. Is that correct? What does index mean? I just started maven so a beginner!

Comment: The file that this is downloading is an index of all the available dependencies available in the Maven central repository for use in Maven-enabled projects, allowing them to be easily chosen and searched against within the Eclipse UI. It is mainly a user convenience, and isn't mandatory.

Comment: there is command way option to copy it, as mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: It will add all dependency in classpath and this error will go. From your question i thought you are talking about the error which eclipse shows even after downloading all dependencies